# vagrant, how to change dhcp to localhost?

Tags: vagrant

I have a vagrant virtual machine installed in my windows, first when I used to do :
vagrant ssh I got:
[vagrant@localhost ~]$

but now :
vagrant ssh I got:
[vagrant@dhcp-10-196-60-23 ~]$

Can you please tell me how to go back to :
[vagrant@localhost ~]$

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you have something like the following defined in your Vagrant file, and it's taking the IP from your dhcp server. Try commenting that out.

`config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"`

Comment: I did not see anything that has dhcp in the vagrantfile, but when I comment : # config.vm.network "public_network" it works. thanks.

Comment: I have another question plz, Do you know how to connect to the guest machine from the host one ?

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on what you're asking. Isn't "vagrant ssh" working for you?

Comment: Ok, just saw you posted another question with more information.